# Need to change page location for a Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a WP blog around an existing website.

The previous website still needs to exist at index.php the blog section exists in the same folder but at news.php

I've installed wordpress and then overwritten the wordpress index with the old websites index.

However whenever links are generated for individual posts for example...

```
<?php wp_get_archives('title_li=&type=postbypost&limit=10'); ?>
```

I'm redirected to the index.

How can I change the Wordpress settings so that `news.php` can be my index and `index.php` remain outside of the WP system.

Comment: Sounds like your old site is using index.php so you're using single.php as the wordpress entry point. Is that right?

Comment: I think you might be going about this in a more difficult way than you need to. WordPress has a built-in mechanism for routing requests to custom URLs. Permalinks in WordPress parlance---the default index.php that comes with WordPress would be referred to as a front controller in other frameworks. You're having this trouble because WordPress wants to route all of its requests through index.php (the front controller). If it were me, I'd let WordPress take over index.php and use WordPress to setup a permalink structure for your new content. Then add 301 redirects for all the old pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some advises.

1. Rather than trying to get a hold of main index file, install wordpress in a sub directory, news/. After that you can change WP Admin->Settings->General: Wordpress Address and Site Address.
2. Move your current index.php to home.php. And then URL-rewrite *all index.php calls without the presences of ?p* to home.php

Comment: In the end changing from new.php to news/ by re-installing was the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. turn on permalink
2. edit .htaccess and change

   **RewriteRule . /index.php [L]** to 
   **RewriteRule . /news.php [L]**

let me know if that works